# Jquery and AJAX for txt file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

This is the script I have

```
<div id="result"></div>
<script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('#year li').click(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    //alert('text is ' + text);
    $.post("B.php",
    {
    text: text,

      } );  
    event.preventDefault() ;
  });
</script>
```

it executes a php script when a list item is clicked. The script *B.php* creates a few txt files. lets call one of them *ddd.txt*. Now I want to load the contents of the file *ddd.txt* onto the div with id **result** when the click has been made. Can someone help me with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `php file` add the following code

```
$file = 'ddd.txt';
$contents = file($file); 
$string = implode($contents); 
echo $string;
```

In your `post success` add the you will get this value that is being `echoed` from the `php` file .suppose it is named `data`

```
$('#result').text(data);
```

Hope this helps u mate.. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$.post("B.php",{ text: text}, function(data){
    $('#result').text(data);
});
```

Or if jQuery >= 1.5:

```
$.post("B.php",{ text: text}).done(function(data){
    $('#result').text(data);
}).fail(function(){
    console.log('something went wrong', arguments);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options. The "syncronous" method where you load the results in the generator request. Or the "asyncronous" method, that you check for results every x seconds after the generator runs.

Syncronously you could do

```
$.post("B.php, { 'text': text }, function(return_data, txtStatus, jqXHR) {
    $('#result').html(return_data);
});
```

and have your php generate the file(s), and output the data you want to display before ending the script.

Asyncronously, there are several options. The easiest method is to use `$().load`, where you would do:

```
function check_results(text) {
    $('#results').load('somescript.php', { 'text' : text }, function(return_data) {
        if(return_data == "") {
            setTimeout(function(){ check_results(text); }, 1000);
        }
    });
}


$.post("B.php, { 'text': text }, function(return_data, txtStatus, jqXHR) {
    check_results(text);
});
```

Essentially, as soon as the POST returns, you start checking for files. If this script generates lots of files and takes some time, but you want to get, for example, the first file, you could run the check results function in-tandem with the post by calling it outside of the post callback function (which is more true to being asyncronous i guess).

Obviously the code is an example, so take with a pinch of salt, you will eed to modify it.

Comment: By no mean this is synchronous - the sync / async thing just applies to code flow [i.e. executing a callback when data is received].

Comment: @moonwave99 Hence why i placed them in quote marks, to emphasise that it's not really sync/async, however compare the two different solutions, and you can see where i was going with it.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this complete action via $.ajax().

```
$('#year li').click(function(){
    var text = $(this).text();
    $.ajax({url: 'B.php', type: 'POST', data: {'value':text}, success: function(data){
        alert(data); // alert any return values;
    }
    });
});
```

And in B.php you can use the $_POST['value'] variable to post the contents to the file, with it you can also add whatever content you like in clean php code.